# Unwanted extra dimensions in NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, dimensions

I've opened a .fits image:

```
scaled_flat1 = pyfits.open('scaled_flat1.fit')   
scaled_flat1a = scaled_flat1[0].data
```

and when I print its shape:

```
print scaled_flat1a.shape
```

I get the following:

```
(1, 1, 510, 765)
```

I want it to read:

```
(510, 765)
```

How do I get rid of the two ones before it?

Comment: For what it's worth, nothing about this is particular to `pyfits`.  If you check the array's header (for example by entering `scaled_flat1a[0].header` at the Python command prompt) you'll see that it likely has `NAXIS = 4` with `NAXIS3 = 1` and `NAXIS4 = 1` resulting in the extra dimensions.  PyFITS returns arrays as standard Numpy arrays so you're best off looking into what Numpy tutorials are out there (I have no specific recommendations though).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is the method called [`squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) which does just what you want:

> Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> ```
> a : array_like
>     Input data.
> axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional
>     .. versionadded:: 1.7.0
>
>     Selects a subset of the single-dimensional entries in the
>     shape. If an axis is selected with shape entry greater than
>     one, an error is raised.
> ```
>
> ### Returns
>
> ```
> squeezed : ndarray
>     The input array, but with with all or a subset of the
>     dimensions of length 1 removed. This is always `a` itself
>     or a view into `a`.
> ```

for example:

```
import numpy as np

extra_dims = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1, 1, 5, 7))
minimal_dims = extra_dims.squeeze()

print minimal_dims.shape
# (5, 7)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming `scaled_flat1a` is a numpy array? In that case, it should be as simple as a `reshape` command.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 6, 7]]]])
print(a.shape)
# (1, 1, 2, 3)

a = a.reshape(a.shape[2:])  # You can also use np.reshape()
print(a.shape)
# (2, 3)
```

Comment: Be careful with this, if you don't always have exactly two extra dimensions at the beginning you may change the effective shape.