# Remove square brackets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, flatten

I have this ouptut:

```
[[[-0.015,  -0.1533,  1.    ]]

 [[-0.0069,  0.1421,  1.    ]]

...

 [[ 0.1318, -0.4406,  1.    ]]

 [[ 0.2059, -0.3854,  1.    ]]]
```

But I would like to remove the square brackets that are leftover resulting as this:

```
[[-0.015  -0.1533  1.    ]

 [-0.0069  0.1421  1.    ]

 ...

 [ 0.1318 -0.4406  1.    ]

 [ 0.2059 -0.3854  1.    ]]
```

My code is this:

```
XY = []
for i in range(4000):
     Xy_1 = [round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), 1]
     Xy_0 = [round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), 0]
     Xy.append(random.choices(population=(Xy_0, Xy_1), weights=(0.15, 0.85)))

Xy = np.asarray(Xy)
```

Comment: Have a look at squeeze: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unwanted extra dimensions in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453587/unwanted-extra-dimensions-in-numpy-array)

Comment: For python list we can reduce 1dim by using `sum` i.e `sum(nested_list,[])` will reduce 1dim. For numpy array refer what @BramVanroy @Georgy have linked in the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to remove 1 dim from array

```
>>> np.squeeze(Xy)
array([[ 0.3609,  0.2378,  0.    ],
       [-0.2432, -0.2043,  1.    ],
       [ 0.3081, -0.2457,  1.    ],
       ...,
       [ 0.311 ,  0.03  ,  1.    ],
       [-0.0572, -0.317 ,  1.    ],
       [ 0.3026,  0.1829,  1.    ]])
```

Or
reshape using[`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```py
>>> Xy.reshape(4000,3)
array([[ 0.3609,  0.2378,  0.    ],
       [-0.2432, -0.2043,  1.    ],
       [ 0.3081, -0.2457,  1.    ],
       ...,
       [ 0.311 ,  0.03  ,  1.    ],
       [-0.0572, -0.317 ,  1.    ],
       [ 0.3026,  0.1829,  1.    ]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try extend method.

```
Xy.extend(random.choices(population=(Xy_0, Xy_1), weights=(0.15, 0.85)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one `random.choices(population=(Xy_0, Xy_1), weights=(0.15, 0.85))[0]`

```py
XY = []
for i in range(4000):
     Xy_1 = [round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), 1]
     Xy_0 = [round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), round(random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 4), 0]
     # Pythonic way :-)
     Xy.append(random.choices(population=(Xy_0, Xy_1), weights=(0.15, 0.85))[0])

Xy = np.asarray(Xy)
print(Xy)
```

**Output**

```py
[[ 0.3948  0.0915  1.    ]
 [ 0.4197 -0.344   1.    ]
 [-0.4541  0.3192  1.    ]
 [ 0.3285  0.0453  1.    ]
 [-0.0171 -0.3088  1.    ]
 [ 0.2958 -0.2757  1.    ]
 [-0.1303  0.1581  0.    ]
 [-0.4146 -0.4454  1.    ]
 [ 0.0247  0.325   1.    ]
 [-0.227   0.139   1.    ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to remove 1dim using `sum`.

```
a=[ [[-0.015,  -0.1533,  1.    ]],
    [[-0.0069,  0.1421,  1.    ]],
    ...
    [[ 0.1318, -0.4406,  1.    ]],
    [[ 0.2059, -0.3854,  1.    ]] ]

sum(a,[])
'''
[[-0.015,  -0.1533,  1.    ],
  [-0.0069,  0.1421,  1.    ],
  ...
  [ 0.1318, -0.4406,  1.    ],
  [ 0.2059, -0.3854,  1.    ]]
'''
```